# Repeating Alarms vs Sync Adapter, which one should I use?

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-syncadapter

I'm developing an Android app whose basic behavior is to show the user some pieces of information every certain configurable period of time. Those pieces of information come from my own server, so the app requests the server for new information whenever it is needed. Its behavior should be something like [Muzei](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.muzei).

And here comes my question, should I use Repeating Alarms to fire a Service that does the job of downloading the new information, or should I use a Sync Adapter?

I've been reading about both methods, but I'm not very sure about which one is the best solution.

Thanks in advance